# Doctrine2 OneToMany inverse persistance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Okay... I feel stupid for asking this but...

I have an entity with the following Entities:

Vendor:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SRC\Bundle\MarketingBundle\Entity\Ad", mappedBy="vendor", cascade={"all"})
 *
 * @var Collection|Ad[]
 */
protected $ads;

/**
 * Returns all vendor ads.
 *
 * @return Collection|Ad[]
 */
public function getAds()
{
    return $this->ads;
}

/**
 * Sets all vendor ads.
 *
 * @param Collection $ads
 */
public function setAds(Collection $ads)
{
die("SET ADS. DIE! DIE!");
    $this->ads = $ads;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Adds vendor ad.
 *
 * @param Ad $ad
 */
public function addAd(Ad $ad)
{
    if (!$this->hasAd($ad)) {
        $ad->setVendor($this);
        $this->ads->add($ad);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Removes vendor ad.
 *
 * @param Ad $ad
 */
public function removeAd(Ad $ad)
{
    if ($this->hasAd($ad)) {
        $this->ads->removeElement($ad);
        $ad->setVendor(null);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Checks whether vendor has given ad.
 *
 * @param Ad $ad
 *
 * @return Boolean
 */
public function hasAd(Ad $ad)
{
    return $this->ads->contains($ad);
}
```

Ad:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SRC\Bundle\VendorBundle\Entity\Vendor", inversedBy="products", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @var Vendor
 */
protected $vendor;

/**
 * Get vendor.
 *
 * @return Vendor
 */
public function getVendor(){
    return $this->vendor;
}

/**
 * Set vendor.
 *
 * @param Vendor $vendor
 */
public function setVendor(Vendor $vendor){
    $this->vendor = $vendor;

    return $this;
}
```

The problem exists in the Vendor CRUD, when I update the ads "setAds()" is never called, as you can see the die() in there, which is never executed. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: When did you try to call `setAds()` ? With which method do you 'update the ads' ?

Answer (score 0):

Prefer an "add" method to the "set"

```
public function addAd(\SRC\Bundle\MarketingBundle\Entity\Ad $ad)
{
    if(!$this->ads->contains($ad)) {
        $this->ads[] = $ad;
    }
    return $this;
}

public function removeAd(\SRC\Bundle\MarketingBundle\Entity\Ad $ad)
{
    $this->ads->removeElement($ad);
}

public function getAds()
{
    return $this->ads;
}
```

I assume your probably calling a **setVendor** method in the Ad class to perform the relation, to sync both sides do something like this :

```
public function setVendor(Vendor $vendor){
    $this->vendor = $vendor;
    $vendor->addAd($this);
    return $this;
}
```

You should also init the ArrayCollection in your Vendor constructor :

```
public __construct()
{
    $this->ads = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: `$vendor->addAd($this)` might be a little bit too much logic to put into your entities. kriswallsmith recommends setting up an event listener on the prePersist/preUpdate to separate that logic from the actual model.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but that's a lot of code for a simple stuff :(

Comment: It will also allow you to delete your entities and recreate them with Doctrine Migrations without worrying about losing custom getters/setters you had in place.